# Подсчитать количество комбинаций

Tags: строки, математика, комбинаторика

Как посчитать количество комбинаций строки состоящей из 10 символов, где используются только латинские буквы в нижнем регистре и цифры.

Очень бы хотелось узнать формулу.

Comment: по формуле, как еще то. в засимости от того могут ли быть повторы.

Comment: только уникальные значения

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Всего символов - 36.

Если повторы могут быть - на первое место сколькими способами можно выбрать символ? 36. Для каждого первого сколькими можно выбрать второй? 36. Итого - 36*36. Для каждых первых двух... - ну, и так далее.

Всего - 36<sup>10</sup>.

Для алфавита  из N символов и длины строки m - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если повторов быть не может - то на второе место - уже только 35 (один уже выбран), на третье - 34 (выбраны уже два)... И так далее. Итого - 36*35*34*33*32*31*30*29*28*27 = 36!/26!.

Для алфавита  из N символов и длины строки m - число *размещений*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: общую формулу то хоть написали бы тогда

Comment: @teran Если бы здесь принимался TeX - запросто, но - https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6310/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0-tex ...

Answer (score 3):

Могут быть использованы две формулы.

Если символы могут повторяться, то любой из 10-ти символов может принимать одно 36 значений (26 латинских букв плюс 10 цифр). Можно сказать, что это 10-тизначное число в 36-ричной системе счисления. Количество комбинаций будет равно 36<sup>10</sup> или 3,6561584×10<sup>15</sup>.

Если символы не могут повторяться, то мы имеем дело с *размещениями*. Есть ещё *сочетания*, но в данном случае они не подходят, потому что размещения `123abc` и `abc123` будут разными, а вот сочетание это будет одно и то же.

Количество размещений из *n* по *k* считается по формуле A<sup>k</sup><sub>n</sub> = n!/(n - k)!, то есть в вашем случае это будет 36!/26! или 9,2239326×10<sup>14</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Используемый алфавит содержит 36 символов: 26 букв и 10 цифр.

Число размещений без повторов = n!/(n-k)! = 36!/26!
Число размещений с повторами = n<sup>k</sup> = 36<sup>10</sup>

Answer (score 0):

кол-во комбинаций = С!

Т.е. в вашем случае 10! комбинаций...

Comment: оу, все сложнее чем показалось на первый взгляд. Ща подумаем.

Comment: то есть в вашем ответе не важна длина алфавита и наличие повторов?